# change .NET Framework in Jetbrains Rider IDE

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, rider

I started building a project and used

```
grid[row, column] = (Status) RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(0, 2);
```

but I am getting an error that I have a wrong `.NET` framework. The error is caused by `.GetInt32`. According to [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com), I need this:

- .NET 5.0
- .NET Core    3.0
- .NET Standard    2.1

and my IDE has this:

- .NET Core 5.0.100
  (in the Settings -> Environment section)

Any advice?
Thanks.

Comment: ".NET Core 5.0" probably means .NET 5.0 (they rebranded .NET Core 5+ as just ".NET", emphasizing that's where new development should occur).

Comment: Did you download the latest version of .net core? `https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download` I am sure that Rider would update its version whenever you update your version in your windows. If you are in Linux or Mac check the path. And .NET Core 5.0.100 does not even exist, the latest is 3.1

Comment: .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5. You can't use both .NET Core 3.1 and .NET Core 5. Apart from that, what is `RandomNumberGenerator` ? That's not a .NET class. The .NET class is named `Random`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos using System.Security.Cryptography

Comment: Are you trying to use the `System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator` instead of `Random` perhaps? The `GetInt32` method was added in .NET Core 3.1. If you want to use that method you'll have to target .NET 3.1 at least

Comment: In .NET Old versions you'll have to create a new class instance with `RandomNumberGenerator.Create` and retrieve random bytes with `GetBytes` and convert them to an Int32

Comment: var rand = new Random(); 
grid[row, column] = (Status)rand.Next(0, 2); did the thing as well.